# lighten mixin with css variables not working

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I'm trying to use the sass mixin `lighten` with css variables but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**CSS**

```
:root {
       --primary-color: 2, 0, 182;
     }


    .btn--primary {
      width:100px;
      height:20px;
      display:block;
      background: rgba(var(--primary-color), .85);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(var(--primary-color), 1) 0%, lighten(rgba(var(--primary-color)), 10%) 85%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(var(--primary-color), 1) 0%, lighten(rgba(var(--primary-color)), 10%) 85%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(var(--primary-color), 1) 0%, lighten(rgba(var(--primary-color)), 10%) 85%);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Send</button>
```

Comment: you cannot. SASS is a preprocessor and come before CSS and cannot read CSS variable

Comment: if you want to consider CSS variable you need to do this in CSS. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330103/8620333