# Use CSS variables and Sass mixing together without Sass vars

Tags: css, sass

I want to user `var(--darkGrey)`. So far I have tried this:

```
$grey: #ddd; // I'd like to remove this line
:root {
  --grey: #ddd;
  --darkGrey: darken($grey, 55%); // doesn't fail but doesn't work
  --darkGrey: darken(#ddd, 55%); // doesn't fail but doesn't work
  --darkGrey1: #{darken($grey, 55%)}; // works but I don't like having a Sass var
  --darkGrey2: #{darken(var(--grey), 55%)}; // fails: "var(--grey)" is not a color for `darken'
  --darkGrey3: #{darken(#ddd, 55%)}; // works but I'd need to use a css var. I have plenty of colors and references
}
```

Comment: `--darkGrey1: #{darken(#ddd, 55%)};` ?

Comment: that works also but I don't only have a color reference I have many other colors using other variables so I don't want to repite any of them.

Comment: you cannot use a CSS varialbes inside a SASS function

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329996/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it does not make much sense to use CSS custom property (variable) in Sass function. CSS custom properties could be changed deeper in your CSS structure or even during the runtime, while Sass is available only during compile time. It could not react to such change.

Have a look at `hsla()` CSS function, which can be used to change lightness of colors during runtime. See article https://sparanoid.com/note/css-variables-guide/.

Comment: that looks good but I can't find an easy way to make the color darker. Found this `filter` property but that applies a filter to the whole div including child elements

Comment: but well, that's a different matter anyway. The main problem is fixed