# CSS equivalent of SCSS lighten

Tags: css, sass, styled-components

I have this SCSS: `background-color: lighten($baseColor, 15%);`

And we're converting our codebase to `styled-components` using inline CSS:

```js
export const animateLoading = ({ baseColor, speed = "700ms" }) => css`
  &:after {
    background-color: lighten(${baseColor}, 15%);
    // etc
  }
`;
```

But `styled-components` uses CSS not SASS so the `lighten` function doesn't work. Does anyone know what that function does, like mathematically or something, such that I can write a JS function to get the same result?

### Update:

Thanks to commenters I've written this, but it's not working. I'm not seeing any color at all:

```js
export const animateLoading = ({ baseColor, speed = "700ms" }) => css`
  &:after {
    --color: ${baseColor};
    background-color: hsl(var(--color), 15%);
    // ...
  }
`;
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330103/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd mark your answer as a dupe for this question, since the `lighten` (which has been advised against using in favor of `color.scale`) uses `hsl()` to do this: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#scale

Comment: Here's the `hsl()` spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()