# Possible to set hex color opacity independently?

Tags: css, css-variables

Is it possible to set `opacity` value in hex color independently (to avoid repetition), or to append to `var()` e.g. `var(--set1)1`?

Example:

```css
:root {
  --set1: #abc;
  --set1-1: #abc1;
  --set1-3: #abc3;
  --set1-5: #abc5;
}


pre {
  border-left: 4px solid var(--set1);
  background-color: var(--set1-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the near future and thanks to ["relative color syntax"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors) You can do the following

```css
:root {
  --set1: #abc;
  --set1-1: rgb(from var(--set1) r g b / 80%);
  --set1-3: rgb(from var(--set1) r g b / 50%);
  --set1-5: rgb(from var(--set1) r g b / 30%);
}
```

You transform the color into an `rgb()` value then you set the transparency.

---

There is no browser support for the above. Until then, you have to manually write the colors or use Sass to generate them.

Related: [How to create color shades using CSS variables similar to darken() of SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329996/8620333)